# "Connection String 'RgaAppDBEntities' could not be found in App.Config" preventing me from adding a WinForm User Control

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework-6

I am creating a WinForms application using Entity Framework 6 and DevExpress UI Components. I've been developing this application successfully for about 2 months, and today I needed to add a new user control to the main window. To my surprise, the designer of the main window displayed an error screen with a couple of exceptions. I clicked "Ignore and Continue" (Which may be the source of my problems).

So here is the issue: After clicking ignore and continue, apparently the designer removed two of my custom user controls (which were the two controls that have implemented Entity Framework so far). When I try to add the user control back to the designer,
[an error pops up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIozP.png) stating that it cannot create the component, and it cannot find the connection string in the application config file.

I've determined the reason I cannot add the user control is because the two user controls causing the issue create an instance of "RgaAppDBEntities", which is the database model I am using.

My data model is in a separate class library project. The App.Config file in both the class library and the WinForms project have:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="RgaAppDBEntities" connectionString="sensitive connection string information generated from database first model" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

The Db Context class constructor looks like:

```
public RgaAppDBEntities()
        : base("name=RgaAppDBEntities")
    {
    }
```

Getting rid of the "name=" results in a UnintentionalCodeFirstException(), so that tells me that for some reason, the WinForms project cannot actually find the connection string named RgaAppDBEntities in the config file, and I am out of ideas.

Finally, I completely got rid of the data model and regenerated the entire model again, and reimplemented everything I needed to, but it still cannot find the connection string in the app.config files.

What could be the cause of this issue, and how can I fix it?

**SOLUTION**

GertArnold's suggestion was correct: when you try to make EntityFramework read app.config during design time, it will complain and not allow you to through exceptions.

In my case, I initialized the database contexts in the constructor of each control's viewmodel, which of course was initialized at run time. As a work around, I just created a method that initializes the database contexts that can only be called at run time. Works like a charm.

Comment: That probably means you added code that tries to connect at design time. Try to move that code to methods that only run at run time.

Comment: @GertArnold Would this just push the problem to run time then?

Comment: @GertArnold Thank you for the help though, this did fix my problems!